# how to take checkpoint record and process remaining data from foreach c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sharepoint

I have multiple files to be process from list.

If because of any reason list is interrupted ,  when next time we execute program it takes the last executed records and start process the further records instead start from 0 index.

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                            <Query>
                            </Query>
                        </View>";
camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 

foreach (var item in listItems)
{
    if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
    {
```

For example I have 10 files to process.
After each file I'm saving file name into log so I have last executed filename.
If because of any reason program shutdown , when we run next time it should take the next file to process instead take it from start.

Any thing I can do like checkpoint here ?

Comment: I am not sure if that could be valid in your scenario but one way is to change the file name once it is processed and just rename it to `_Processed` that way next time you pick up files which are !`_Processed`

Comment: where you can save that as process in log? how/where you can maintain that list and check remaining files into listItem from sharepoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, add a column in the SharePoint list or document library to hold the status if it has been processed or not. Then you just need to update your CAML query so that it pulls all the records which have not been processed yet. Then in your `foreach` loop update the record you just processed and update its status.

This way, new records will be processed and processed records won't be pulled in your CAML query. This also makes sure you won't be retrieving records which have been processed already.

Comment: This is great approach thank you but I have thousands of libraries with me I cant add column in each file right now.
Is there anything we can do with database or somewhere to identify processed files?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The best approach would be to add these columns via powershell or CSOM so that you dont have to do them manually.